# Highcharts - event on error 12?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When creating a HighCharts chart and the series of data objects is too big, a console message is written out:

```
Highcharts error #12: www.highcharts.com/errors/12
```

Is there any way for the code to be notified when that happens? I don't see any event that is raised. Also, when done like this...

```
var x = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function (chart) {
   // error?
}
```

...the callback function is still called and the `chart` object is nicely filled out. But there is no indication that an error occurred.

If I look inside the chart object, I can guess that something went wrong, because the `xAxis` min and max are both undefined, and other oddities.

It would be nice if the `chart` object could have a property so that, say, `chart.error == 12`.

Comment: What is your data format? Could you post a sample? You could increase [`turboThreshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) to disable turbo mode or you could change your data format to the required one. Error managing function in Highcharts is not wrappable, so you would have to make changes in core code and use that custom file or wrap function that are reporting the errors - using function that prints error to a console. More about wrapping functions in the [Docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

Comment: I already warn the user when the number of data points is over the `turboThreshold`. All I'm asking for is that when the tool writes an error message to the console, it should also let the code know! Simply setting a property of the `chart` object would be enough!

Comment: You can find similar question with possible solution on Highcharts github https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3590
There is a chance that this functionality will be present in future Highcharts releases.